# Pre-Load Custom Cursors With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload, mouse-cursor

I have been able to successfully preload image gallery before page loads but was wondering how I could do the same for custom cursor.cur files as it doesn't work using the image method below as it cant understand .cur extension?

```
// Image Preloader
var pictures [
    "a.jpg",
    ..
    "z.jpg"
];

for (var i=0;i < pictures.length; i++){
    var img = new Image()
    img.src = pictures[i];
    img.onload = function(){
        updateProgress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set it in CSS on an element that is not visible (or just very small). I think the cursor will be loaded as soon as the CSS is loaded. You can, of cource, do the same with JQuery, although the code may be executed later.

Comment: It wont. It will load once its called by the cursor itself. Think :hover in css, the images only load once a hover has occured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the ico file using an AJAX `.get()` and ignore the response. The response should be cached in the browser. Something like:

```
    $.get('/favicon.ico', function() {
        alert('Loading of ICO file completed!');
        // Do other processing here
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BGG2m/

Comment: Worked great could pre-load multiple cursors on pre-load splash page. By the way I meant to say .cur not .ico in my post.